# how to retrieve NSURLRequest's HTTPBody params to Dictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject] in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

I am attempting to convert a `NSURLRequest`'s `HTTPBody` from `NSData` to a `Dictionary`, so that access it's parameters and run a check.

```
 var parameters: [NSObject: AnyObject?] = [
            "method": "foo",
        ]
        var urlRequestString = "www.foobar.com/api/aMethod"
        var urlRequest = AFOAuth2Manager().requestSerializer.requestWithMethod("POST",
            URLString:urlRequestString ,
            parameters: postParameters,
            error: nil)
```

in another method, I am attempting to run a check on the `urlRequest` being constructed above to ensure that the `"method"`  in the NSURLRequest contain's the right value `"foo"`.

What i need is to convert the `HTTPBody` to a `Dictionary` ( `[NSObject: AnyObject]`) 
 so that i can check to see if the `"method"` parameter contains the value I need.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func queryDictionaryForQueryString(query: String) -> Dictionary<String, String> {
    var dictionary = [String: String]()

    for keyValueString in query.componentsSeparatedByString("&") {
        var parts = keyValueString.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
        if parts.count < 2 { continue; }

        var key = parts[0].stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
        var value = parts[1].stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!

        dictionary[key] = value
    }

    return dictionary
}
```

then you can

```
let httpBody = urlRequest.HTTPBody
let httpBodyString = NSString(data: httpBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
let queryDictionary = queryDictionaryForQueryString(httpBodyString)
println(queryDictionary["method"])
```

Comment: "let httpBodyString = NSString(data: httpBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String" is returning nil for me. httpBody is NSMutableData at my place and the conversion to String doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my more Swifty 3.0 NSURL extension to accomplish this with nil safety:

```
extension NSURL {

    var paramsDictionary: [String : String]? {

        guard let parameterString = parameterString else {
            return nil
        }

        var dictionary: [String : String] = [:]
        parameterString.components(separatedBy: "&").forEach {
            let componants = $0.components(separatedBy: "=")
            guard let name = componants[0].removingPercentEncoding, let value = componants[1].removingPercentEncoding else {
                return
            }
            dictionary[name] = value
        }
        return dictionary.isEmpty ? nil : dictionary
    }
}

var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.testWebSite.com/index.php;param=value&testParam=test&thingParam=thing")
let params = url?.paramsDictionary //results in "Optional(["thingParam": "thing", "testParam": "test", "param": "value"])"
```